# React state not updating in time with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Update: Problem found - the onChange event is fired on component render, this overwrites what happens in the useEffect... not sure how to address this conflict, might have to dig into the installed component.

Update 2: "Solution" was to put a setTimeout in the onChange event for the slider, and a slightly longer setTimeout on the useEffect so that they resolved in the correct order.

I'm using a slider component in react from [here](https://github.com/developergovindgupta/multi-range-slider-react-ts) - it is working properly.

I am trying to update the minimum and maximum slider values + the actual value of the sliders whenever a `chartData` set is updated using useEffect();

Despite setting some states within useEffect, these states aren't being rendered by the component.

The `chartData` is being retrieved asynchronously from the backend, which may contribute to this problem.

Here is my code:

```
//Histogram block size
  const blockSize = 5000;

  //Initial boundaries for histogram slider
  const initialMin = 15000;
  const initialMax = (labels.length-1)*blockSize;
  
  const [max, setMax] = useState(initialMax);

  //States for histogram slider
  const [minValue, setMinValue] = useState(initialMin);
  const [maxValue, setMaxValue] = useState(initialMax);

  //Update histogram sliders when new data is input
  useEffect(()=>{
    setMax(initialMax)
    setMinValue(initialMin)
    setMaxValue(initialMax)
  }, [chartData])

  //Handle histogram sliding
  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setMinValue(e.minValue);
    setMaxValue(e.maxValue);
  };

  
  return (<div className = 'Chart' style={{position: 'relative', width: "62vh"}}>
     <Bar options={options} data={data}/>
     <MultiRangeSlider
            min={0}
            max={max}
            step={blockSize}
            minValue={minValue}
            maxValue={maxValue}
            onChange={(e) => {
                handleInput(e);
            }}
    />
```

Chart data is coming from:

```
//chartData state passed to Chart component
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(initialChartData);

  const buttonClickFunction = ()=>axios.get('/api/v1/data', {'params': ['python', 'javascript' , 'c++']})
    .then((res)=>{
      setChartData(res.data);
    });
```

As part of the rendered component:

```
...
<Chart chartData={chartData}></Chart>
...
```

Comment: Please include ALL the relevant code. For example where is ```chartData``` coming from?

Comment: Would it help to only render the component once the chartData is available?